# sorting in excel error when duplicate data

Tags: sorting, excel-formula

I am trying formula for sorting of a column in excel. Data is entered in one column and sorted data is output in another one. Please see attached excel file.

[image]

As you can see due to same data in second column I am getting rank 2 twice and VLOOKUP cannot find entry named 3 so it is giving error. When all data entered are unique there is no problem but in case of duplicated data I am having problem. What can I do?

Kbv.

Comment: What is the purpose of the column "Rank of Data"? Is it just a helper column or a column for controlling a custom sort?

Comment: yes. VLOOKUP function finds this ranks and shows associated data. first cell finds 1 from rank column then second cell finds 2 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed a third possibility that you miight be looking for. So you want to sort the `B` items where column `A` indicates the rank of each item in `B`:

```
C2
=VLOOKUP(SMALL($A$2:$A$7,ROW(1:1)), $A$2:$B$7, 2,FALSE)
```

[image]

---

Old answer:

If you want a custom sort where column A indicates the rank of the resulting item in`C` , copy the following formula in `C2` and fill down.

```
C2
=SMALL(B$2:B$7,A2)
```

If you want just to copy the column as sorted "naturally", you dont need any helper column, just type this in the first row and fill down (I used column `D` in my example image below):

```
D2:
=SMALL(B$2:B$7,ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello A.S.H
thanks for your answer. your D column formula works for me. And also for descending I can use LARGE instead of SMALL.

Comment: @KushantVyas yes, exactly. glad to help:)